# Unity InputField Text disappears when button is clicked

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my Unity project I have a InputField that a user can type into and click a button to trigger an action preformed based on what they entered. When I type into the InputField and then press the button, the text that was entered empties before I am able to grab it using `inputtedFieldName.text`

I have a InputField with the button as a child. The InputField has a component that attaches the script. Attached to the button is a method is called when the button is pressed. It appears when the button is pressed the text that was in the inputField disappears.

What can I do to fix this?

Method the button is calling

```
public void EnterTextToConsole() {
    if (textInputted.text == "" ) {
        ConsoleLog.addToConsole("NOTHING??");
    } else {
        ConsoleLog.addToConsole(textInputted.text);
}
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what you mean by disappear... Is the InputField gone or the Text in it. When it disappears, can you print the InputField value and see if it's still there ...`Debug.Log(inputtedFieldName.text);`. Maybe a screenshot of what exactly is going on would be helpful.

Comment: The text in it disappears. I have user a Debug.Log in my Update function to see what is going on. When I click the button and before the method is called the text inside the input field disappears.

Comment: You mean that  `Debug.Log(inputtedFieldName.text)` shows something but after the button is clicked `Debug.Log(inputtedFieldName.text)` becomes empty?

Comment: That is what I mean.

Comment: Post the function the button is calling.

Comment: I posted the method. All that is printed out when the method is called is "NOTHING??" when the button is clicked and something has been entered into the inputField

Comment: Well I didn't expect to see that.  I thought you were doing something unexpected in that function. *A button cannot magically change or reset a TextInput. You are either changing `inputtedFieldName.text` from script or from the Editor or maybe you are loading new scene when the button is clicked. Can you upload screenshot of the Button component in the Inspector tab that shows the onClick settings. Also, a screenshot of the InputField in the Inspector tab